# Link to string using json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I add new items to a table that come as JSON data. I have a name, price, category, and a link. How can I make it so that when I click on a particular line I visit the link associated with that item?

HTML

```
<main>
    <table id= "userdata" >
        <thead>
            <th>title</th>
            <th>category</th>
            <th>price</th>
        </thead>
    </table>
</main>
```

JavaScript

```
$(function() {
    $.getJSON('catalog.json', function(data) {
        $.each(data.catalog, function(i, f) {
           const tblRow = "<tr>" + f.link + "<td>" + f.title + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.category + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.price + "</td>"  + "</tr>";
            $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata ");
      });
    });

    $(document).on('click', 'tr', function(){
        console.log(this.link);
     });
 });
```

Item data

```
{
    "catalog": [
        {
            "title": "ФТ-45",
            "category": "Шкаф",
            "price": 200,
            "link":"/1.html"
        },
        {
            "title": "Наташа",
            "category": "Диван",
            "price": 300,
            "link":"/2.html"
        },
        {
            "title": "Peter",
            "category": "Шкаф",
            "price": 400,
            "link":"/3.html"
        },
        {
            "title": "Сокол",
            "category": "Кресло",
            "price": 400,
            "link":"/4.html"
        }
    ]
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind a click event handler to the rows you create that can take the link for the row and put use it for the browser location to redirect to the link location.

```
$(function() {
  $.getJSON('catalog.json', function(data) {
    $.each(data.catalog, function(i, category) {
      let $tblRow = $(
        "<tr><td>"+ category.title +
        "</td><td>"+ category.category +
        "</td><td>"+ category.price +
        "</td></tr>"
      );

      $tblRow.on('click', function(e){
        window.location = category.link;
      });

      $tblRow.appendTo("#userdata");
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Add a custom data value to row elements.

```js
$(tblRow).data("item-index", i)
```

Then you can get this value using

```js
var index = $(this).data("item-index");
console.log(data[index]);
```